# Pachislo Token Sensor Optical sensor replacement part#?

Tags: identification, photosensor, optical

[image: photo of PCB showing optical sensors]

Pachislo Token Sensor Optical sensor

As shown above I have a Pachislo Mazya Dynamite Kid's Machine which has a bad Token Sensor Booard. Can someone please advise on what a suitable replacement part can be used for the 2 Optical Sensors? I haven't been able to find the depicted part# P1018 00: or the Manufacture symbol it has.

Comment: Those look like "typical" [photointerrupters](https://www.rohm.com/electronics-basics/photointerrupters/what-is-a-photointerrupter). Since these were found in a toy, they are probably generic parts made of 100% genuine Chinesium. You can find similar devices in old multi-function printers, of from a [wide variety of manufacturers on Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/optical-sensors-photointerrupters-slot-type-transistor-output/548). Just be aware that fixing this board will probably not be worth your time/money.

Answer (score 1):

That's a "light barrier"/photointerruptor.

Armed with dimensional and supply voltage knowledge, and deriving LED current from that (by guestimating a 2V forward voltage and doing the series resistor math), you could probably find compatible replacement parts [on one of the large distributor websites](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/optical-sensors-photointerrupters-slot-type-logic-output/547?FV=-8%7C547&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25).

Considering this board's component selection looks like the 1980s, it's unlikely that the original part is still on stock anywhere: it's not high-volume / cheap enough a part that it got produced in the billions, and it's not valuable / mission-critical enough for defense-specific electronic stockholders to have it.

By the way, I'd start with unsoldering every single one of these glass diodes very carefully and checking whether they still act as diodes – I'd expect them to be more susceptible to failure than the photodiode in the photointerruptor.

Whatever you do, start with drawing and tidying up a full schematic of this board – pretty much impossible to get the right polarities and voltages if you don't have a clear idea of how the photointerruptor integrates into that part.